# Transposing a non-unique single column to variable names in R

Tags: r, transpose

This is my sample data.

```
  Uid   category Pur_amt Week_number
  103   fashion       25           3
  104      kids       63           2
  104  fashion        12           3
```

I want to transpose this table into this format .

```
 Uid  category  X2 X3
  103  fashion   0 25
  104  fashion   0 12
  104     kids  63  0
```

In the real dataset, I have around 16000 observations, week number varies between 1 and 52 (I want 52 columns).